# How do I add a wishlist button on home page to newest product?

Tags: wishlist

This is the list.phtml where I display the newest products on homepage.

```
<?php

$collection = $this->getProductCollection(); 
$_collectionSize = count($collection);
$_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount();

?>

<div class="sama_productblocks_grid">
    <h3 class="divider-h3"><?php echo $this->getTitle();?></h3>

    <div class="sama_productblocks_descrition"><?php echo $this->getDescription();?></div>

    <?php $i=0; foreach ($collection as $item): ?>

    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
    <ul class="products-grid column-<?php echo $_columnCount;?> newest-products-list">
    <?php endif;?>

        <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $item['url']?>" title="<?php echo $item['name']?>" class="product-image">
                <img src="<?php echo $item['image']?>" width="<?php echo $this->getThumbnailWidth();?>" alt="<?php echo $item['name']?>">
            </a>
            <h2 class="product-name">
                <a href="<?php echo $item['url']?>" title="<?php echo $item['name']?>"><?php echo $item['name']?></a>
            </h2>

            <div class="price-box">
                <p class="regular-price">
                    <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($item['finalprice'], true, false);?>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="add-to-cart-main">
                <a href = "<?php echo $item['url']?>" class="add-to-cart">
                    <div class="cart-elements">
                        <span class='add-to-cart-img fa fa-arrow-right'></span>
                        <span class='add-to-cart-text'><?php echo $this->__('View details');?></span>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href = "#Ineed here a wishlist url"  class="wishlist fa fa-heart-o" > 
                </a>

            </div>
        </li>

    <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
</div>
```

I tried to introduce this piece of code to get the wishlist url:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
```

but with no result. So how do I get a wishlist button ? or a wishlist url where I typed "I need a wishlist url" ? on the homepage. Thx in advance

This is the getProductCollection function:

```
public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $useCache = Mage::app()->useCache('SAMA_PRODUCTBLOCKS');
        $cacheData = Mage::app()->loadCache($this->getCacheTags());

        if ((empty($cacheData) && $useCache) || !$useCache) {
            $productCollection = $this->_currentList->getSelectedProductsCollection();

            $collection = array();

            foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
                $collection[] = array(
                    'name' => $product->getName(),
                    'image' => (string)$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(max(100, (int)$this->_currentList->getThumbnailWidth())),
                    'url' => $product->getProductUrl(),
                    'price' => $product->getPrice(),
                    'finalprice' => $product->getFinalPrice(),
                    'sku'       => $product->getId(),
                    'qty'       => $product->getIsInStock()
                );
            }

            Mage::app()->saveCache(json_encode($collection), $this->getCacheTags(), array($this->getCacheTags()));
        } else {
            $collection = json_decode($cacheData, true);
        }

        return $collection;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `#Ineed here a wishlist url` with

```
 <?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($item) ?>
```

**[EDIT]**
Also you don't need to loop through the collection and load each product separately, then generate an array from them. It's a real performance killer.

you can replace this;

```
        foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
            $collection[] = array(
                'name' => $product->getName(),
                'image' => (string)$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(max(100, (int)$this->_currentList->getThumbnailWidth())),
                'url' => $product->getProductUrl(),
                'price' => $product->getPrice(),
                'finalprice' => $product->getFinalPrice(),
                'sku'       => $product->getId(),
                'qty'       => $product->getIsInStock()
            );
        }

        Mage::app()->saveCache(json_encode($collection), $this->getCacheTags(), array($this->getCacheTags()));
```

with this:

```
         Mage::app()->saveCache(json_encode($collection->toArray()), $this->getCacheTags(), array($this->getCacheTags()));
```

Comment: This is the website: http://latesthoes.mediaswitch.ro/ . If you check the newest product , there will be a heart image. I put the code as you suggested, but it displays the only the base url.

Comment: I guess he doesn't know about $_product.What should it be the $_product ? a collection or the sku  ?

Comment: Yep. sorry. It should have been `$item` instead of `$_product`. I edited my answer.

Comment: It is also the same , I checked with firebug and the href is empty. any idea ?

Comment: See my new edit.  It's empty because `$item` in your case is an array and it should be an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`

Comment: if i changed the loop foreach and the Mage::app ... with  Mage::app()->saveCache(json_encode($collection->toArray()), $this->getCacheTags(), array($this->getCacheTags())); . He does know about the $collection. so I changed it with  $productCollection. But with no any result

Comment: it was a return type problem.I still returned the $colection instead of the $productCollection. Thx for your help!!!

Comment: The code it works, but i am getting 302 redirect issue, after I clicked on the wishlist button. any idea why ?

Comment: you are getting redirected to the login page, right? That's normal. wishlist works for logged in customers only.

Comment: Right. but after that when i logged in and i want to add a product to  the wishlist, instead of redirecting me to the wishlist list , it remains stuck at this: .... /wishlist/index/add/product/607/form_key/gHIrYwcdJhgvuuXx/ - for example. and it shows me this message: The page isn't redirecting properly